Calculation of the diffusion coefficient of a Lennard-Jones fluid (liquid argon)
I'm trying to simulate with the code written by Professor Cameron Abrams(https://github.com/Abrams-Teaching/instructional-codes/blob/main/originals/mdlj_and.c), a set of argon atoms interacting by a Lennard Jones potential coupled with a stochastic thermostat (Anderson or Dissipative particle dynamics). However when I try to calculate the self-diffusion coefficient from the Einstein relation, the result is totally different from that obtained by Rahman in his famous article ((https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.136.A405)). The condition of the simulation, which I've chosen, is after all, the same of Rahman's, that is 864 particles at a density of 1.364 $\frac{g}{cm^3}$
and a temperature of 94.4 K. How is it possible this discrepancy? In reduced units, I obtain 5.27⋅$10^{-9}$
, while the expected result is 0.0456. Is there anyone who has experience with molecular dynamics here?

